# Parse string in Elixir

Tags: string, elixir

I want to parse a string in Elixir. It obviously is binary. 
I want to get the value of `left_operand`, it is '2', but I am not sure how to do it. Because it's like a string, list, tuple mix stuff.

```
iex(13)> str = "[{\"start_usage\":\"0\",\"left_operand\":\"2\"}]"
iex(15)> is_binary str
true
```

The string is JSON format retrieved from MySQL.
I want to use the devinus/poison module to parse it, but I'm not sure how to deal with the first and last double quotes (`"`).

It seems that I just need the tuple part so I can do it like

```
iex(5)> s = Poison.Parser.parse!(~s({\"start_usage\":\"0\",\"left_operand\":\"2\"}))
%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}
iex(6)> s["left_operand"]
"2"
```

But I don't know how to get the tuple part.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I think I figured out how to do it my way.

```
iex> iex(4)> [s] = Poison.Parser.parse!("[{\"start_usage\":\"0\",\"left_operand\":\"2\"}]")
[%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}]
iex(5)> s
%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}
iex(6)> s["left_operand"]
"2"
```

I am not sure why this works, **I didn't pass the `~s` prefix**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tuple part that you are looking for is actually a [map](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/maps-and-dicts.html#maps).

The reason your original version didn't work is because your JSON, when decoded, returned a map as the first element of a [list](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#%28linked%29-lists).

There are multiple ways to get the first element of a list.

You can either use the `hd` function:

```
iex(2)> s = [%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}]
[%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}]
iex(3)> hd s
%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}
```

Or you can pattern match:

```
iex(4)> [s | _] = [%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}]
[%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}]
iex(5)> s
%{"left_operand" => "2", "start_usage" => "0"}
```

Here [destructuring](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching) is used to split the list into its head and tail elements (the tail is ignored which is why `_` is used)

This has nothing to do with the type of the elements inside the list. If you wanted the first 3 elements of a list, you could do:

```
iex(6)> [a, b, c | tail] = ["a string", %{}, 1, 5, ?s, []]
["a string", %{}, 1, 5, 115, []]
iex(7)> a
"a string"
iex(8)> b
%{}
iex(9)> c
1
iex(10)> tail
[5, 115, []]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you parse a JSON string with Poison, there's no way for it to know if the values inside the JSON object are an integer or something else other than a string. To get the number `2`, you can do:

```
~s({"start_usage":"0","left_operand":"2"})
|> Poison.Parser.parse!
|> Map.get("left_operand")
|> String.to_integer()
```